# Copy Excel sheet from one workbook into another retaining named ranges definitions

Tags: excel, vba

I have an Excel workbook with a lot of named ranges, both with scope Workbook and also Worksheets (worksheets are generated dynamically, so their number is variable).
Now, whenever I try to copy one these dynamically created worksheets from one workbook into the other, all named ranges of the source workbook are also transferred to the target workbook, but with scope set to Worksheet (name of copied worksheet).
It there any way to force the copied worksheet to keep the range definitions with scope Workbook of the target workbook (which are exactly the same)?
If this would not be feasible using Excel's worksheet copy feature, how could this be achieved using VBA?

Comment: inherit the original name via creating a function which copies the range and it's associated name (ie. replace the new name with the old name - and watch out for errors)

Comment: Why don't you just `Saveas`the workbook then leave the sheets you want to copy and delete the rest. It serves what you want withou complexity.